# A web based data item with selectable columns?

Tags: asp.net

This probably has a simple answer, but I've been looking all over and can't find anything to suit my needs.

I've been using gridviews to display data, but new customer requirements call for the user to be able to select individual columns, rows, or cells. Does anyone know of a good option?

Thanks.

EDIT:

Essentially, I'm displaying several rows of data, each row comprised of multiple columns. With standard gridviews you can't really select all the data in one column without selecting data from the other columns. I need a way for the user to select one column worth of data so that they can copy the data out.

Comment: What you mean by "Select indidual columns , rows..." ? Just highlight it on click ?

Comment: Something along the lines of being able to click on a column header and have the results of that column highlighted. Or possibly just being able to select 'sections' like excel. I'm considering just trying to figure out how to embed excel, but that's not ideal.

Comment: Checkout the jQuery grid plugins

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for commercial solution, check out Infragistics NetAdvantage for ASP.NET. Example of grid in action: http://www.infragistics.com/products/aspnet/sample/data-grid/selection-client-events